# Concatenating a column into a variable

Tags: sas

Hi there pretty simple question I think, I have a record like this for example :

```
name value
Mack 12
Mack 10
Mack 50
```

Now I want to put all the value in a variable or a single row. The result should be

```
value_concat
12,10,50
```

I try to use the first and last statement with SAS but it not working for me here is what I wrote :

```
data List_Trt1;
    set List_Trt;
    by name;

    if first.name then  value_concat = value;
    value_concat = cats(value_concat,",",value);
    if last.name then value_concat = cats(value_concat,",",value);

run;
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: I removed the [tag:sql] as this has no reference to SQL. If you have a reason for including it, such as preferring a SQL solution, please note so in the Q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track.

```
data List_Trt1;
  set List_Trt;
  by name;
  length value_concat $30; *or whatever is appropriate;
  retain value_concat;
  if first.name then value_concat=' ';
  value_concat=catx(',',value_concat,value);
  if last.name then output;
run;
```

First, you need retain so it keeps its value throughout.  Second, you need to initialize it to blank on `first.name`.  Third, you need to output only on `last.name`.  I use `CATX` because it is more appropriate to what you are doing, but your `CATS` should be okay also.